# Unable to npm install npm package

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, nvm

I've been trying to figure out why I can't install `[node-qt]` and `[node-core-audio]` on my `Mac OSX` `[10.12 Sierra]`

It has been throwing errors at me with the latest version of node and with 8.0.0, 4.0.0 that I tried with nvm.
Here’s a screenshot of the error that I’ve been getting. 
[[image]

Can anyone please help with solving this? I’ve no clue of what’s going, even though my other node packages seem to work fine

Answer (score 0):

Binary packages (things that require compilation) are often incompatible with new major versions of node that come out.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-qt was published 6 years ago - this will likely never be usable in the future, unless you can file an issue and convince the maintainer to update it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-core-audio was last published a year ago, and has open issues describing the compatibility problems:
 - https://github.com/AudioNet/node-core-audio/issues/49
 - https://github.com/AudioNet/node-core-audio/issues/56

https://github.com/AudioNet/node-core-audio/issues/69#issuecomment-266571187 appears to be the last time it was addressed.